# How are you supposed to use NUnit 3.2?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

How do I use NUnit 3.2? I can't find a tutorial specifically for versions `>= 3`, and the other ones I found lead the problems. I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/07/27/getting-started-with-net-unit-testing-using-nunit.aspx).

First off, the tutorial says that from VS you can go to `Test -> Windows -> Test Explorer` to run your tests. However, this didn't seem to detect any tests I had in my class library project, even after building.

Second, there's no GUI for v3, so that's out of the question.

Third, the tutorial mentions the console version of NUnit. To be clear, I installed `NUnit Console Version 3` from NuGet. The tutorial says it's name is `nunit-console.exe`, and it's located in the `bin` folder of the location you installed `NUnit`. Well it appears that v3 and higher don't create a `bin` folder, however the `nunit-console.exe` doesn't run. Double clicking on it brings up the console for a fraction of a second, then closes it immediately. There's also an `nunit-agent.exe` file and an `nunit-agent-x86.exe` file, but both of them crash upon running so I assumed I should just leave them alone.

Now I'm stuck. How exactly does one use NUnit 3.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various different methods to run NUnit 3 tests...

> First off, the tutorial says that from VS you can go to Test ->
>   Windows -> Test Explorer to run your tests.

To make this work, you will need to install the "NUnit3 Test Adapter". Install it through `Tools>Extensions and Updates` in Visual Studio. Make sure you get the v3 adapter and not the v2 adapter - they're separate extensions.

> Second, there's no GUI for v3, so that's out of the question.

Currently under development! Follow it's progress: [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-gui)

> Third, the tutorial mentions the console version of NUnit.

This is probably the most conventional method. The console can be installed as either a standalone program (Download an installer [here](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=download)), or as a Nuget package. (I'd use the `NUnit.Runners` package - it includes some sensible default extensions that `NUnit.Console` does not.) This is then installed wherever your packages go (normally the `packages` dir in the root of your project?), you can add a reference and `Copy Local` if you want to run it in `bin`. The console itself is now named `nunit3-console.exe` - to run tests, simply pass your test project to that exe on the command line. e.g.

```
nunit3-console.exe MyTests.dll
```

Finally, you could also try the `NUnitLite` Nuget package. [[Docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnitLite-Runner)] This will turn you test project into an executable, so that your tests will run themselves. We found this really helpful for downstream integration.

Given you seem to just be looking for a simple solution to run tests, I'd recommend the NUnitLite package, or the VS adapter.

Comment: Okay, I installed the `NUnit Test Adapter for VS2012, VS2013, and VS2015`, but the version is listed as `2.0` and I can't seem find version 3 on NuGet. Installing this did nothing unfortunately.

Also, I have `NUnit.Runners.3.2.0` in my project `packages` directory, however it's completely empty except for a `NUnit.Runners.3.2.0.nupkg` file. The `NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.2.0`  folder however does contain a `nunit3-console.exe`. Can you elaborate more on the process of adding `Copy Local`?

Comment: @user3002473: This is the extension you want. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d

Comment: That's the correct exe under NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.2.0 - NUnit.Runners adds various packages which reference each other, from memory. Don't worry about copy local, NUnit Lite would be better if you wanted to do it that way! But you should be able to pass the path to your test project to that exe, as the example above. =)